# Why won't the first character of my x-axis display in plot?

Tags: r, plot

I want my x-axis to show the range 0 to 6 (7 ticks in total).  I enter the following data, but the 1st character doesn't show - so the final tick has no label, and the 0 doesn't appear. (I tried using a non-zero number at the start and that still didn't work, so I know that's not the issue!)
My coding is this:

```
x=0:6

probdist = dhyper(x,6,30,6)

plot(probdist, main="Probability Distribution Function", xlab = "Amount of Numbers Matched", ylab="Probability of Amount of Numbers Matched", xaxt = "n")

lab = c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6")

axis(side=1, at = x, labels = lab)
```

How can I get the `x-axis` to show the range 0 to 6 on it?  Just using the `plot` function, with `xaxt = "n"` removed, results in the range 1 to 7.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Add `xlim=range(x)` to your `plot` function and you're good to go.

```
x=0:6

set.seed(1234)
probdist = dhyper(x,6,30,6)

plot(probdist, main="Probability Distribution Function", xlab = "Amount of Numbers Matched",
     ylab="Probability of Amount of Numbers Matched", xaxt = "n", xlim=range(x))

lab = c("0","1","2","3","4","5","6")

axis(side=1, at = x, labels = lab)
```

This returns

[image]

The reason that the `axis` function does not add a 0 is because the plot has already been created, and it is just modifying the existing plot.

Comment: Yay, it now shows the 0 on the x-axis! However, the data has been moved to the right - there is no data point appearing for "0", and the data point that is supposed to be for zero is appearing above the 1 tick. (the highest data point is when x = 1 - not 2 as showing in your plot)

Comment: @Jessie Just write `xlim = c(1,6)` in that case.